# css position absolute off center to the left

Tags: css

I'm trying to position a div box off center and to the left. It must be absolute positioning and I can't wrap it within another div as it's generated by a very long js script.

Here's my css so far:

```
.nivo-html-caption {
  position:absolute;
  top:59px;
  opacity:0.8;
  transition:all 0.8s ease-out;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  width: 350px;
  color: #cbcbcb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

I'm using the `margin:auto;` to center it and the `top:59px;` to push it down from the top. But I now need to push it off center to the left about 300px.

I'm not quite sure how to do this without wrapping it in another div or putting another div inside it (which I really don't want to start doing as it's going to take a lot of messing around)

Comment: what's your reasoning for needing absolute positioning? would `margin-top` suffice? like as such: `margin: 59px auto 0;`

Comment: Combination of `absolute position`, `float` and `margin: auto`? Why not :-) Please create a fiddle and let's do it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's positioned *absolute*, instead of centering it using margin: auto, try this:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -175px;
```

This will centre it and adjusting the margin-left will take it off centre.

Comment: If you read the last line and apply that to your fiddle I think you'll find that it works...

Answer (score 6):

Your request is a little unclear but you first need to center the item and then move it over 50% of the required adjustment.

```
.nivo-html-caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:59px;
    left:50%; 
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* centered first regardless of width*/
    margin-left: -175px; /* then moved over */
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:59px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin-left: -175px;
    opacity:0.8;
    transition:all 0.8s ease-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    width: 350px;
    color: #cbcbcb;
    padding: 10px;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="nivo-html-caption"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`margin: 0 auto` will not get you the right results if `position` is set to `absolute`, so try:

```
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0px;
```

this will make the div stick to the left side. and vertically center

example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1xzLLgh3/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this : **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6ju4c5o7/1/)**

```
h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:59px;
    opacity:0.8;
    transition:all 0.8s ease-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    width: 350px;
    color: #cbcbcb;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1> Text half center </h1>
```

I tried to align it in center using `left` and shifted half using `margin-left`